# Convert Formula Numerical Value to Matched Strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have the following formula that checks a username against a range of usernames, determines whether that username belongs to one of three domains, and whether that username is marked as an Administrator:

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Tbl_Data[Username],Rng_ITEmp,Tbl_Data[Domain],{"D1","D2","D3"},Tbl_Data[Member of Groups], "*Administrators*"))`

This formula works wonderfully!  I'd like to dig a little deeper though and actually print out the usernames that satisfied this query.  Is there a way to go from this equation to the values that came back as TRUE?

Comment: I don't have data to test but try this first `=INDEX(Tbl_Data[Username],SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Tbl_Data[Username],Rng_ITEmp,Tbl_Data[Domain],{"D1","D2","D3"},Tbl_Data[Member of Groups], "*Administrators*")*ROW(Tbl_Data[Username]),1)`.  This should return the string from the `Username column`.

Comment: I just get an #N/A value as a result.  :(  I'll keep poking around though, this seems like a good start.

Comment: Try to do `SUMPRODUCT` in another column and see if that returns the correct row number.